# how to load drawables from /drawable-hdpi instead of /drawable android?

Tags: android, image, size, drawable

When i run my app on android 2.3 emulator, without creating the /drawable directory, images are loaded from the drawable-hdpi directory.
But when i create the /drawable directory, images are loaded from the drawable instead of the drawable-hdpi directory. I have create the drawable folder to make my app to run also on android 1.5.
What should i do to load images from drawable-hdpi/mdpi/ldpi on android >=1.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources that are loaded are specific to the target that the application is being run on. If the phone is an HDPI qualified phone, then it will load those resources.. if its MDPI then it will load those resources...

**You shouldn't be setting these directly, because this is handle specifically by the frameworks.**

Comment: but then why is the problem occuring in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

The rules used by Android to find the best matching resources at runtime are explained [in this document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch).

Especially:

[image: flowchart]